Unable to upload file to ADLS Gen2 with Microsoft Entra ID(Service Principal) Authorization
I'm trying to upload a file to ADLS Gen2 storage with Microsoft Entra ID(Service Principal) Authorization.
Getting below error message while uploading a file to ADLS gen2 using DataLakeServiceClient
com.azure.storage.file.datalake.models.DataLakeStorageException: Status code 400, "?
<Code>MissingRequiredHeader</Code><Message>An HTTP header that's mandatory for this request is not specified.
RequestId:adad-dads-d-20a2-xxdadad
Time:2024-05-07T17:18:58.0750289Z</Message><HeaderName>x-ms-type</HeaderName></Error>

DataLakeServiceClient dataLakeServiceClient = new DataLakeServiceClientBuilder()
        .endpoint("https://<storageaccount>.file.core.windows.net/")
        .credential(new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId("<client_id>")
                .clientSecret("<client_secret>")
                .tenantId("<tenantId>")
                .build()).buildClient();
                
        DataLakeFileSystemClient container  = dataLakeServiceClient.getFileSystemClient("test");
        
        DataLakeDirectoryClient directoryClient = container.getDirectoryClient("upload").getSubdirectoryClient("customer_info");
        
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream("hello".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        long fileLength;
        try {
            fileLength = stream.available();
        
            DataLakeFileClient fileClient = directoryClient.createFileIfNotExists("test.csv");
            //fileClient.cr
            fileClient.upload(stream, fileLength);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

POM.xml
`<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-storage-file-datalake</artifactId>
    <version>12.18.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-keyvault-secrets</artifactId>
    <version>5.11.0</version>
</dependency>

`
Is there a way to resolve the issue?


Unable to upload a file to ADLS Gen2 with Microsoft Enterprise ID (Service Principal) Authorization.

You can use the code below to upload a stream into Azure Data Lake Storage using Java.
Code:
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredentialBuilder;
import com.azure.storage.file.datalake.DataLakeDirectoryClient;
import com.azure.storage.file.datalake.DataLakeFileClient;
import com.azure.storage.file.datalake.DataLakeFileSystemClient;
import com.azure.storage.file.datalake.DataLakeServiceClient;
import com.azure.storage.file.datalake.DataLakeServiceClientBuilder;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DataLakeServiceClient dataLakeServiceClient = new DataLakeServiceClientBuilder()
            .endpoint("https://<storageaccount>.file.core.windows.net/")
            .credential(new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
            .clientId("<client_id>")
            .clientSecret("<client_secret>")
            .tenantId("<tenantId>")
            .build()).buildClient();

        DataLakeFileSystemClient container = dataLakeServiceClient.getFileSystemClient("test");
        DataLakeDirectoryClient directoryClient = container.getDirectoryClient("upload").getSubdirectoryClient("customer_info");

        String content = "Name,Age,City\n" +
                 "John Doe,30,New York";

        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        long contentLength = content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length;

        DataLakeFileClient fileClient = directoryClient.getFileClient("test.csv");
        fileClient.upload(stream,contentLength);
        try {
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

In the above code, to upload a file in the filesystem, you need to use the dfs endpoint.
Output:
The code above is executed and uploaded as a CSV file in my filesystem.

Reference:
DataLakeFileClient Class | Microsoft Learn
